# Passing Airflow Context to init_container in KubernetesPodOperator

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kaniko, kubernetespodoperator, git-sync

Airflow's `KubernetesPodOperator` provides an `init_containers` parameter, with which you can specify kubernetes [init_containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/). However `init_containers` expects a list of `kubernetes.models.V1Container`, and I don't see any way to pass airflow context (or xcoms) to these containers. Is that possible?

Context: I want to use [git-sync](https://github.com/kubernetes/git-sync) and [kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko) to build an image from a private repo. Kaniko doesn't support cloning using a deploy key, so I want to use git-sync as an init-container to clone the repo for the kaniko pod. However, I need a way to pass the correct URL and key from airflow to the init container. I can imagine a solution that uses `pod_mutation_hook` to extract context from the main pod, but that seems inelegant.

---

Here is what I would like to do. Note that my use of the kubernetes api may be inexact, however the issue I'm trying to solve is templating into the `'GIT_SYNC_REPO'` env variable.

```py
from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.kubernetes_pod import KubernetesPodOperator
from kubernetes.client import models as k8s


cloner = k8s.V1Container(
    name="clone-repo",
    image="k8s.gcr.io/git-sync-amd64:v2.0.6",
    env=[
        # Problem: No templating occurs on this line. 
        k8s.V1EnvVar(name="GIT_SYNC_REPO", value="{{ dag_run.conf['repo_url'] }}"),
        k8s.V1EnvVar(name="GIT_SYNC_SSH", value="true"),
        k8s.V1EnvVar(name="GIT_SYNC_ONE_TIME", value="true"),
    ],
    ...
)

build_container = KubernetesPodOperator(
    name="create_container_name",
    task_id="create_container",
    image="gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest",
    init_containers=[cloner],
    image_pull_secrets=[ecr_image_pull_secret],
    arguments=[
        '--context=path/to/volume/containing/cloned/repo',
        '--destination={{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="Setup")["sandbox_container_url"] }}',
        "--cache=true",
    ],
    secrets=[ecr_rw_credentials],
    dag=dag,
    service_account_name="airflow-worker",
)
```

Comment: This is a question about Airflow and passing airflow context to its `KubernetesPodOperator`. I'm writing code to do this, so it sure feels like programming to me.

Comment: Yes, `KubernetesPodOperator` specifically.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will add some code illustrating what I'd like to do

Comment: My comment will self-destruct shortly.

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-passing-data-between-tasks), `XCom` should only be used for small data. It seems that intermediary data storage is a better fit. This would allow to have checkut and build in two different steps, no need for init containers.

Comment: Here I would like to use `XCom` to pass the repo url. I agree that passing data between containers is better done with some other mechanism.